# React-native flex - View element does not display

Tags: flexbox, react-redux

I am learning RN and am practising layouts with flex. In the code below the View element with text LOGO appears in the 'footer' but does not render in 'header'.

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class groceryApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: 'myState'};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.header}>
          <View style={styles.leftbox}>
            <Text>LOGO</Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.main}>
          <View style={styles.box}><Text>111</Text></View>
          <View style={styles.box}><Text>{this.state.text}</Text></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
          <View style={styles.box}></View>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <View style={styles.leftbox}>
            <Text>LOGO</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center', // or 'space-between'
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    // 'flex-start', 'flex-end', 'stretch', 'center'
    // for 'stetch' you have to remove fixed size from secondary from elements
  },
  header: {
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'powderblue',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  main: {
    height: 450,
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  footer: {
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'steelblue',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  box: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    margin: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  leftbox: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('groceryApp', () => groceryApp);
```

What am I missing here? The footer and header class seem identical so how is it different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Logo text is there...you just can't see it because of the Dimensions of the screen.

You are using fixed height dimensions within your flex containers...that is not ideal.  The total screen height is less than all the heights you've declared.  Stick to just flex, and not an absolute height for the containers.

change the style of `header` `alignItems` to `flex-end` and you shall see your text.  Alternatively wrap your content in a `ScrollView` and you shall also see what is happening.